# Swift ContainerView UI gesture not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a View including a Container View which renders ViewControllers (Based on selected tab in TabBar)

When I try to click on the button (Which has a gesture/target event) it does not output anything in the console. UI Interaction is enabled on all views.

[image: Button in UI]
That's how I include the ViewController into the ViewContainer

```
let windowView = view.viewWithTag(1)
let contentView = view.viewWithTag(2)
let loginView = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginView")

currentView = loginView.view
contentView?.addSubview(loginView.view)
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Please post a minimal code that helps reproduce the issue. That'd help provide quicker and accurate answers.

Comment: @SepDev you need to include more code, like which struct/class represent the button "EINLOGGEN" in order to check how you design it and how you attached to it a tap gesture recognizer

Comment: Best guess - you are instantiating `let loginView = storyboard!...` in the same function where you are adding its `.view` to `contentView` -- and then exiting the function. At that point, `loginView` (the viewController code) goes out-of-scope.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, I created two container views with their child views, and now show them based on the selected tab.